# Get serialized stdClass values

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, deserialization

I have an SQL query:

`$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS key_value FROM wp_customker WHERE ker_name = '1'");`

If I run this query I'll get 176 element in a serialized stdClass:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [key_value] => a:176:{i:0;s:10:"Ág utca ";i:1;s:14:"Aladár utca ";i:2;s:11:"Alag utca ";i:3;s:14:"Alagút utca "...;} ) )

I've tried to convert it to an Array with
 `$array = json_decode(json_encode($query), true);`
 got this result:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [key_value] => a:176:{i:0;s:10:"Ág utca ";i:1;s:14:"Aladár utca ";i:2;s:11:"Alag utca "...;} ) )

My question is how could I unserialize this data and `echo` all the Strings in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Check for [maybe_unserialize()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) function in wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in `key_value` has been serialized and not json encoded

So for example you can do this to get at the original data

```
$serial_data   = $query[0]->key_value;
$unserial_data = unserialize($serial_data);

foreach ( $unserial_data as $key=>$val) {
    echo $key . ' = ' . $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WP get_results funtion takes a second argument

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("
         SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS key_value FROM wp_customker WHERE ker_name = '1'", ARRAY_N);
```

Comment: yes if I do that I'll get my 2nd result without encode and decode, but it's still serialized or I dunno why, but I can't iterate it through a foreach loop.

`foreach ($query as $item => $value) {
                echo $value;
            }`
returns with
` Array` and if I var_dump or print_r I'll get the original array